# array to pointer issue in C program

Tags: c, arrays

Here is the program which i am working on.

```
void primMST(int graph[N][N])
{
     int parent[N] ; // Array to store constructed MST
     int key[N];   // Key values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut
     bool mstSet[N];  // To represent set of vertices not yet included in MST
     int i, count, v;

     // Initialize all keys as INFINITE
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        key[i] = INT_MAX, mstSet[i] = false;

     // Always include first 1st vertex in MST.
     key[0] = 0;     // Make key 0 so that this vertex is picked as first vertex
     parent[0] = -1; // First node is always root of MST 

     // The MST will have N vertices
     for (count = 0; count < N-1; count++)
     {
        // Pick thd minimum key vertex from the set of vertices
        // not yet included in MST
        int u = minKey(key, mstSet);

        // Add the picked vertex to the MST Set
        mstSet[u] = true;

        // Update key value and parent index of the adjacent vertices of
        // the picked vertex. Consider only those vertices which are not yet
        // included in MST
        for (v = 0; v < N; v++)

           // graph[u][v] is non zero only for adjacent vertices of m
           // mstSet[v] is false for vertices not yet included in MST
           // Update the key only if graph[u][v] is smaller than key[v]
          if (graph[u][v] && mstSet[v] == false && graph[u][v] <  key[v])
             parent[v]  = u, key[v] = graph[u][v];
     }

     // print the constructed MST
     printMST(parent, N, graph);
}



int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int** graph = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
        graph[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("AdjacencyMatrix_of_Graph_G_N.txt","r");
    char c;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%c ", &c);
            graph[i][j] = c-'0';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            printf("%d ",graph[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    primMST(graph);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And i am getting the following warnings.

```
 C:\TURBOC3\BIN\PROJECT\MST.c:125:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'primMST' from incompatible pointer type
  primMST(graph);
          ^
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\PROJECT\MST.c:59:6: note: expected 'int (*)[30]' but argument is of type 'int **'
 void primMST(int graph[N][N])
      ^


Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 2
- Output Filename: C:\TURBOC3\BIN\PROJECT\MST.exe
- Output Size: 132.0068359375 KiB
- Compilation Time: 0.48s
```

Comment: One fix is to change `primMST(int graph[N][N])` to `primMST(int **graph)`

Comment: An array `int graph[N][N]` is a single block of N*N integers. Your array is however an array of pointers, each to an array of N integers. Not the same structure. The compiler is complaining about that. @kaylum's comment gives a solution.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Which line does actually contain an Array of Pointers?

Comment: `int** graph = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);`. This allocates an array of `N` pointers (`int *`).

Comment: No, no, no. Int** means a pointer-to-Pointer to int, or a pointer lookup table, or a dinamicaly multidimensional array, but not an Array Of Pointers. This ==> int *arr[N] is an Array of (N) Pointers

Comment: @Michi an `int **` may point to the first element of an unnamed array of pointers

Comment: [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), section 6.

Comment: @M.M True, but pointing to something doesn't mean that int** is an Array of Pointers. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't see which part from that section says that int** is an Array of Pointers?

Comment: @Michi: No part says that, because an `int**` isn't an array of pointers. Did I  imply that it is?

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry about that. I thought that was there something like that :))

Comment: On a different note, use gcc instead of TurboC.

Answer (score 0):

as people have commented here, and int ** is not the same as int[][], and that is why the compiler complains.

also i can see that you are dynamically allocating a size of N array, this has 2 drawbacks: 
1. malloc is a pretty expensive operation and calling it N times seem unnecessary.
2. the result will not be a continuous block of memory.

assuming that N is a #define, i would suggest allocating graph[N][N] on the stack in main() rather than dynamically allocating it.

Comment: `malloc is a pretty expensive operation and calling it N times seem unnecessary`  I would do it like [This](http://ideone.com/YkxSwF)

Comment: yes, that is also a good way, but it all depends on needs, if i need a small array i better off allocating it on the stack, if i don't know the sizes or the sizes are very large, i would allocate on the heap.